# Logarithmic functions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms

I am stuck on this question which as follows:

$\log(x) + \log(x-3) = \log(10x)$

I have tried the following and not sure if I am doing it correctly...

1)

$$
\log(x) + \log(x-3) = \log(10x) \implies\log((x)(x-3)) = \log(10x)
$$
$$
\implies \log(x^2-3x) = \log(10x) \implies x^2-3x = 10x
$$
$$
x^2-13x = 0 \implies x = 0,x = 13
$$

2)

$$
\log(x) + \log(x-3) = \log(10x)
$$
$$
\log(x) + \log(x) - \log(3) = \log(10x)
$$
$$
x + x - 3 = 10x \implies x = -3/8
$$

Are these approaches on the right path?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first approach is correct. The second is not: $\log(x - 3) \not= \log x - \log 3$.

The next step is to check for extraneous solutions, by verifying which solutions ($x = 0$ and $x = 13$) satisfy the original equation.

Comment: I just want to echo that second point! For any problem, this sort of work does not actually *find* the answer, but merely narrows down the possibilities for what it can be. You have to do more work to check which of the possibilities are actually answers (unless you can guarantee each of your steps are "reversible").

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure if $log(z)$ means $log_{10}(z)$ or $log_{e}(z)$ i.e $ln(z)$, so I will go with convention and assume $log(z) \implies log_{10}(z)$.

Here goes:
\begin{align*}
log(x) + log(x-3) &= log(10x)
\\
log\left( \left(x \right)\left(x-3\right)\right) &= log(10x)
\\
10^{log\left( \left(x \right)\left(x-3\right)\right)} &= 10^{log(10x)}
\\
\left(x \right)\left(x-3\right) &= 10x
\\
x^2 - 3x &= 10x
\\
x^2 - 13x &= 0
\\
x\left(x - 13\right) &= 0
\end{align*}

so $x \in \{0, 13\}$

But for $x=0$ the original equation becomes:
$log(0)+log(-3) = log(0)$.  This is a problem because $log(z)$ is defined only for $0< z$ if $z$ is real.

Logarithms of complex numbers quickly get very messy.  So confining the arguments of the $log$ functions to positive reals leaves a single answer: $x=13$

I hope this was not too much detail.